# prove that functions are bounded if satisfying inequalities with partial derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus

let $f: \mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R}$ be differntiable prove that:

i) f is lower bounded if $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^nx_i \cdot f'_{x_i} \ge 0$

ii) $f \in C^1$ is upper bounded if $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^nx_i \cdot f'_{x_i} \le \frac{1}{||x||}$ for $||x||>1$

I don't know how to approach this problem would be grateful for help

Comment: Fix $x = (x_1,\dots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $g(t) = f(tx)$. Then $g'(t) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}{x_if'_{x_i}(tx)}$.

Comment: ok i'm nut sure if I'm rigth: we have g non decreasing so $g(1)=f(x) \ge f(0)=g(0)$ so it's lower bound for $f$ ?

Comment: That's pretty much correct (although the order of logic should go $f(x) = g(1)\ge g(0) = f(0)$).

Comment: do you know what about ii) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (ii), let's first look at $x$ with $\|x\|>1$. For $\frac{1}{\|x\|}<t<1$, we have
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}{(tx_i)f_{x_i}'(tx)}\le\frac{1}{t\|x\|}$$
(this is condition (ii) applied to the point $tx$). Furthermore, letting $g(t) = f(tx)$, we have
$$g'(t) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}{x_if_{x_i}'(tx)}\le\frac{1}{t^2\|x\|} $$
It follows that
$$ f(x) - f\left(\frac{x}{\|x\|}\right) = g(1) - g\left(\frac{1}{\|x\|}\right) = \int\limits_{1/\|x\|}^{1}{g'(t)\text{ d}t} \le \int\limits_{1/\|x\|}^{1}{\frac{1}{\|x\|t^2}\text{ d}t} = \frac{1}{\|x\|}(\|x\|-1). $$
I will let you finish the proof...